# Subsetting data breaks GLM

Tags: r, binary, subset, glm

I have a GLM Logit regression that works correctly, but when I add a subset argument to the GLM command, I get the following error:

```
invalid type (list) for variable '(weights)'.
```

So, the following command works:

```
glm(formula = A ~ B + C,family = "binomial",data = Data)
```

But the following command yield the error:

```
glm(formula = A ~ B + C,family = "binomial",data = Data,subset(Data,D<10))
```

(I realize that it may be difficult to answer this without seeing my data, but any general help on what may be causing my problem would be greatly appreciated)

Comment: Working!  Would you please explain the difference?

Comment: Perhaps a subset through the index will work: `glm(formula = A ~ B + C,family = "binomial", Data[which(Data$D < 10), ])`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try `subset=D<10` instead (you don't need to specify `Data` again, it is implicitly used as the environment for the `subset` argument).  Because you haven't named the argument, R is interpreting it as the `weights` argument (which is the next argument after `data`).